# how to make syntastic with html tidy aware of ionic tags?

Tags: vim, ionic-framework, tidy, syntastic

I'm trying to edit an ionic application with vim that has syntastic enabled using html tidy.  Unfortunately, I'm getting a load of errors.

How can I make html tidy aware of ionic tags, or failing that make it ignore them so that I don't receive errors like this:

```
www/index.html|26 col 5 error| <ion-pane> is not recognized!
...
www/index.html|24 col 3 warning| <body> proprietary attribute "ng-app"
```

Comment: For the millionth time, Syntastic is a frontend that doesn't do any syntax checking by itself. All the syntax checking is done by external tools so either you find a way to tell those external tools about your specific requirements or you find another external tool that satisfies them.

Comment: Thanks for the education.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution for me was to set the following:

```
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors=["<ion-", "discarding unexpected </ion-", " proprietary attribute \"ng-"]
```

Comment: It's probably better to add `ion-pane` and the like to `g:syntastic_html_tidy_blocklevel_tags`, and only ignore the errors about attributes.  You might also want to try [HTML Tidy for HTML5](http://www.htacg.org/tidy-html5/) instead of `tidy` (cf. syntastic's [wiki](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/HTML%3A---tidy)).

Comment: just curious, have you found any better solution up to this day?