# Vim and Syntastic with non-standard HTML tags

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, vim, ionic3

I'm using Vim with Ionic framework and facing some troubles. Ionic has custom HTML tags and attributes for them. One of plugins I used in Vim - syntastic. So when I save my .html page with Ionic tags I'm getting errors and warnings about those tags. Additionally, Ionic has components with custom selector, so I have some tags like `<user-list></user-list>`.

Is there a way NOT to silencing or ignoring those warnings, but get working syntax checking with Ionic HTML and custom tags? I like to work with syntastic, it provides useful information for me.

I found answers about disabling syntastic for Ionic and/or silencing errors and warnings. It's not what I want to get. Do I have any options? For this moment I think I'm not ready to make my own plugin for Vim, maybe in the future.

Comment: Sure you have: find a HTML linter that is aware of Ionic syntax, and write a syntastic checker for it.  More realistically: try to understand the tools you're using.  As long as the linters you're using have no clue about the syntax of your projects you'll get useless error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to set up vim for typescript and see if syntastic still shows error. Use https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim for syntax and https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi for typescript server. This [article](https://medium.com/@mhartington/typescript-vim-64783d89e468) helped me.

The other way would be to ignore ionic tags by syntastic. Inside [my vimrc](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arysom/06177e95ba483e1c7876c2190d2b5879/raw/39b9430906c820ed624b1583a076b704d67db267/vimrc):

```
" Set up the arrays to ignore for later
if !exists('g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors')
    let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors = []
endif
" Ignore ionic tags in HTML syntax checking
" See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366621
" ignore errors about Ionic tags
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors += [
      \ "<ion-",
      \ "discarding unexpected </ion-",
      \ "plain text isn''t allowed in <head> elements"
]
```

Comment: I'm using both of these, but troubles are with .html and specific HTML tags.

Comment: you could add https://github.com/akz92/vim-ionic2  to your current html syntax, maybe it could help

Comment: With this solution still get error about `<ion-header>` like "text isn't allowed in HEAD`

Comment: your ignore may contain many rules. I've updated my answer. Also take a look https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues/240#issuecomment-56908650 to see more rules

Comment: Thank you, you've answered my question!

Answer (score 2):

My vimrc sources plug-in specific config files. My syntastic config file has the following, which combines some of the answers above with a few other tricks.

```
" Try to use HTML5 Tidy for better checking?
" installed it via homebrew, which puts it in this location
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_exec = '/usr/local/bin/tidy'
" which is better than the version which ships with mac, 
" /usr/bin/tidy/

" Ignore ionic tags in HTML syntax checking
" See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30366621
" ignore errors about Ionic tags
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors += [
      \ "<ion-",
      \ "discarding unexpected </ion-"]
" It's probably better to add ion-pane and the like to g:syntastic_html_tidy_blocklevel_tags, and only ignore the errors about attributes. 

" Angular's attributes confuse HTML Tidy
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors += [
      \ " proprietary attribute \"ng-"]

" Angular UI-Router attributes confuse HTML Tidy
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors += [
      \ " proprietary attribute \"ui-sref"]

" Angular in particular often makes 'empty' blocks, so ignore
" this error. We might improve how we do this though.
" See also https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/HTML:---tidy
" specifically g:syntastic_html_tidy_empty_tags
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors += ["trimming empty "]

" Angular ignores
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_blocklevel_tags += [
      \ 'ng-include',
      \ 'ng-form'
      \ ]

" Angular UI-router ignores
let g:syntastic_html_tidy_ignore_errors += [
      \ " proprietary attribute \"ui-sref"]
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try with this config!